# How to call accept() with non-blocking sockets c++

Tags: network-programming

This my be a silly question, but I'm trying to use non-blocking sockets for the first time,but what I noticed is that when I run the server program it imediately gives me error in `accept()`(`WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, what i have read, this is an usual thing). My question is then,how can I connect to the server then ?
I am using `ioctlsocket` in Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using non-blocking sockets, `accept()` will immediately return if there's no client connection waiting.  You need to check if the error is `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`, ignore it if it is, and use a polling loop to check again later.  The [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function may be useful.